# R merge two data frames by group

Tags: r, merge

my two sample data frames are :

```
dt1 <- data.frame(   
name = c(rep('c',3), rep('b', 2)),   
status = c('1','3','8','9','7'),   
date = c('10-01','10-03','10-04','10-02','10-05')
)

dt2 <- data.frame(date = c('10-01','10-02','10-03','10-04','10-05'))
```

I want to merge `dt1` and `dt2` based on `date` column. That is, I want my result data frame `dt3` to be as:

```
name    statue    date   
 c        1       10-01  
 c        NA      10-02  
 c        3       10-03  
 c        8       10-04  
 c        NA      10-05
 b        NA      10-01  
 b        9       10-02  
 b        NA      10-03  
 b        NA      10-04  
 b        7       10-05
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(dt1, name, date = dt2$date)
```

Here the 'date' column in both 'dt1' and 'dt2' have the same `unique` elements.   If it different and want to use 'date' from 'dt2', the above works well.  Or this can also be done from a single dataset

```
complete(df1, name, date)
```